# Can't handle button action due to "Program received signal: “EXC_BAD_ACCESS”."

Tags: interface-builder, uibutton

Tried to deal with this problem for two days now. 
My app has a text field and a button. when the text field is empty, pressing the button gives me a stable run and i receive an alert after pressing the button.
However, if i am typing something in the text field, then pressing the button - it crashes.
All i can see in the debug console is: 
"Program received signal:  “EXC_BAD_ACCESS”."
There is no stack detail or anything. My relevant code:
the header file:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface SpyTextViewController : UIViewController {

    int sliderSpeed;
    IBOutlet    UITextField     *textInput;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITextField *textInput;




- (IBAction)sliderChanged:(id)sender;//speed of text show changed

- (IBAction)textFieldDoneEditing:(id)sender;//dor 'DONE' on keyboard
- (IBAction)backgroundTap:(id)sender;//for handling tapping on background

- (IBAction)textEmButtonPressed:(id)sender;

@end
```

------  the .m file:

```
#import "SpyTextViewController.h"
#import "txtViewController.h"

@implementation SpyTextViewController
@synthesize textInput;






- (IBAction)sliderChanged:(id)sender
{
    UISlider *slider = (UISlider *)sender;
    sliderSpeed =  (int)(slider.value + 0.5f);//setting the speed determinned by the usr in slider
}

- (IBAction)textFieldDoneEditing:(id)sender
{
    [sender resignFirstResponder];
    NSLog(@"our text input  is %@", textInput.text);
}

- (IBAction)backgroundTap:(id)sender
{
    [textInput resignFirstResponder]; 
}   

- (IBAction)textEmButtonPressed:(id)sender
{
    NSLog(@"our text input length is %@", [textInput.text length]);

    /*
     if ([textInput.text length])
     {
     NSLog(@" inside the tvc init ");
     //create the sub MVC 
     txtViewController *tvc = [[txtViewController alloc] init];
     tvc.scrollSpeed = sliderSpeed;
     tvc.scrollTxt = textInput.text;
     [self.navigationController pushViewController:tvc animated:YES];
     [tvc release];
     //run text using speed;
     }
     else */
    {
        //tell 'em to input text with some pop-up
        NSString *msg = nil;
        msg = @"Write text to transmit";
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Forgot something?"
                                                        message:msg
                                                       delegate:self
                                              cancelButtonTitle:@"Back" 
                                              otherButtonTitles:nil];

        [alert show]; 
        [alert release]; 
        [msg release];
    }
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    // Releases the view if it doesn't have a superview.
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

    // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
}

- (void)viewDidUnload {
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
    // e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;
}


- (void)dealloc {
    [textInput release];
    [super dealloc];
}

@end
```

---

Some detail on the .Xib file:
the action method is attached to file's owner through "touch-up inside".
the text field has its outlet connected to it also (i also printed the contents of the text, it works fine).I also changed the view's class identity to be UICpntrol so i could support the event of tapping on the view while typing txt in the text field so that the keyboard will be exited...

What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

msg string is constant, and releasing it may have caused the exception.

Answer (score 0):

Run under the debugger ("Build and Debug").

The debugger window (cmd-shift-Y) will show the traceback of where the problem occurred, and let you examine variables at that point.